# Error: apex:pageBlock must be the direct parent of apex:pageBlockButtons

Tags: visualforce

I have Created the Visual Force Page :

```
<apex:page standardController = "Contact">
 <apex:form>
 <apex:pageBlock>
 <apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:inputfield label="Mobile #"  value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />





    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Back"/>


                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                 </apex:pageBlock>





  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

with the Account Id as Lookup Relation of all accounts ,i am unable to add the field Label for Particular Look Up Field, while saving it is showing **Error: apex:pageBlock must be the direct parent of apex:pageBlockButtons** How to Rectify the Error

Comment: Move the `<apex:pageBlockButtons>...</apex:pageBlockButtons>` content to just below the `<apex:pageBlock>` opening tag.

Answer (score 3):

Error message says it all. PageBlockButtons should be after the pageBlock component.

```
<apex:page standardController = "Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Back"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputfield label="Mobile #"  value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />
                <apex:outputfield label="Mobile #"  value="{!Contact.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```